# Does the extent of illiteracy in children correlate with future criminality?

Tags: criminology, literature

[Neil Gaiman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Gaiman) recently made what has been hailed as one of the best commencement speeches ever at Philadelphia’s University of the Arts (reported [here](http://www.farnamstreetblog.com/2012/05/neil-gaiman-one-of-the-best-commencement-speeches-ever/), available as a book [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/exec/obidos/ASIN/0062266764/farstrblo-21)).

In it he talks about the value of literacy. As part of his argument he says (i'm quoting from [this report](http://www.farnamstreetblog.com/2013/10/neil-gaiman-reading-libraries/) of the speech):

> I was once in New York, and I listened to a talk about the building of private prisons – a huge growth industry in America. The prison industry needs to plan its future growth – how many cells are they going to need? How many prisoners are there going to be, 15 years from now? And they found they could predict it very easily, using a pretty simple algorithm, based on asking what percentage of 10 and 11-year-olds couldn’t read...
>
> It’s not one to one: you can’t say that a literate society has no criminality. But there are very real correlations.

Is he right? What's the evidence? **Does illiteracy in the young correlate with criminal behaviour later?**

Comment: Are you asking if this correlation exists in the USA or globally? I imagine that there are places in the world where literacy is non-existant.

Comment: @MrFox There are also countries with stronger welfare / social security systems, different policies re imprisonment, etc. The claim made by Neil Gaiman was presumably specific to the USA, so I expect that this question should be too.

Comment: @MrFox I intended the question to be general despite Gaiman's claim using the USA as an example. I suspect, though, that the differences among countries (especially those with low overall literacy) would preclude direct international comparisons for the whole globe. But perhaps this is a discussion to be had in a good answer.

Comment: @ChrisW - what does "stronger welfare / social security systems" have to do with anything? Modern american inner cities have orders of magnitude more "stronger welfare / social security systems" over 150 years ago, and significantly more crime. USSR was a workers paradise where everyone was guaranteed a living and a pension. Didn't get rid of the crime, surprisingly.

Answer (score 7):

There seem to be a lot of statistics that point to that correlation, e.g. see 
[Read, or Go to Jail](http://www.reentrynow.org/1/post/2011/12/read-or-go-to-jail.html) that refers to some relevant statistics:

> - 85 percent of all juveniles who interface with the juvenile court system are functionally illiterate.
> - More than 60 percent of all prison inmates are functionally illiterate.
> - When the State of Arizona projects how many prison beds it will need, it factors in the number of kids who read well in fourth grade
>     (Arizona Republic (9-15-2004)). Evidence shows that children who do
>     not read by third grade often fail to catch up and are more likely to
>     drop out of school, take drugs, or go to prison. So many nonreaders
>     wind up in jail that Arizona officials have found they can use the
>     rate of illiteracy to help calculate future prison needs.
> - Low literacy is strongly related to crime. 70% of prisoners fall into the lowest two levels of reading proficiency(National Institute
>     for Literacy, 1998).
> - Low literacy is strongly related to unemployment. More than 20% of adults read as or below a fifth grade level – far below the level
>     needed to earn a living wage. enal institution records show that
>     inmates have a 16% chance of returning to prison if they receive
>     literacy help, as opposed to 70% who receive no help. This equates to
>     taxpayer costs of $25,000 per year per inmate and nearly double that
>     amount for juvenile offenders.
> - Illiteracy and crime are closely related. The Department of Justice states, “The link between academic failure and delinquency, violence,
>     and crime is welded to reading failure.” Over 70% of inmates in
>     America's prisons cannot read above a fourth grade level. ([Literacy
>     Statistics at
>     Begintoread.com](http://www.begintoread.com/research/literacystatistics.html))

Comment: Please elaborate/summarise to protect us against link rot.

Comment: Ironically the cited blog entry was apparently never proof-read: the same statistics/phrases are repeated two or three times.

Comment: Sighing at the general lack of control data.